# Conditional merging tables

Tags: r, date, merge, data.table, aggregate

I have 2tables:

```
    Time      X1  
  8/1/2013    56 
  9/1/2013    14   
  10/1/2013    8  
  11/1/2013    4  
  12/1/2013   78  

    Time      X2  
  8/1/2013    42 
  9/1/2013    44   
  10/1/2013    2  
  11/1/2013   75  
  12/1/2013   36
```

How can I merge those 2 table in one table grouping by "Time" but with one condition: the month from first table must match with the following month form the second - like September from first table should match with October from second table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect job for `data.table` [rolling join](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dat1)[, Time := as.Date(Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y")], Time)
setkey(setDT(dat2)[, Time := as.Date(Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y") - 1], Time)
dat2[dat1, roll = -Inf]
#          Time X2 X1
# 1: 2013-08-01 44 56
# 2: 2013-09-01  2 14
# 3: 2013-10-01 75  8
# 4: 2013-11-01 36  4
# 5: 2013-12-01 NA 78
```

Edit: If you don't want the unmatched row, use `nomatch = 0`

```
dat2[dat1, roll = -Inf, nomatch = 0]
#          Time X2 X1
# 1: 2013-08-01 44 56
# 2: 2013-09-01  2 14
# 3: 2013-10-01 75  8
# 4: 2013-11-01 36  4
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why did you put `-Inf` ?

Comment: It rolls back and matches the first match no matter how far away it from the current value. If you noticed, I've set `-1` in `dat2`. It will also work with `dat2[dat1, roll = -30]` because we are matching a month back (30 days)

Comment: How can we don`t output thew rows with NAs(with no matches)?

Comment: Thank you! But what if I need to group not only by "Time" but by other parameter as well?