# Conditional merging tables with more conditions (continue)

Tags: r, date, merge, data.table, grouping

This is the continue of the question [Conditional merging tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895474/conditional-merging-tables/26895892?noredirect=1#comment42348071_26895892)

I have 2 tables:

```
  Time      X1  Class
8/1/2013    56    B
8/1/2013    24    A 
9/1/2013    14    A
9/1/2013    46    B
10/1/2013    8    A
10/1/2013   45    A
11/1/2013    4    B
11/1/2013   63    A
12/1/2013   78    A
12/1/2013   39    B
1/1/2014    69    A
1/1/2014    26    B

  Time      X2  Class
8/1/2013    42    B
8/1/2013    46    A
9/1/2013    38    B
9/1/2013    44    A
10/1/2013   29    B
10/1/2013    2    B
11/1/2013   75    A
11/1/2013    6    B
12/1/2013   36    A
12/1/2013   23    B
1/1/2014    83    B
1/1/2014    126   A
```

How can I merge those 2 table in one table grouping by "Time" and by "Class" but with one condition: the month from first table must match with the following month from the second - like September from first table should match with October from second table.

The solution with grouping by "Time" only was offered by @David Arenburg :

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dat1)[, Time := as.Date(Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y")], Time)
setkey(setDT(dat2)[, Time := as.Date(Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y") - 1], Time)
dat2[dat1, roll = -Inf]
```

Comment: Set the key to `Class, Time` instead of just `Time`, and repeat the same. You should put some effort and go through the examples in `?data.table`.

Comment: @Arun Thank you! I tried to use setkey(setDT(dat1)[, Time := as.Date(Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y")], c(Time,Class)) but get the error. I am not very good with data.table Could you please help me?

Comment: Set it to `Class, Time`. Not `Time, Class`. And you should go through the docs and learn about a package before using it.

Comment: @Arun Thanks! Send me the link on docs, please.